# Angular LoggedIn method

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

How can I add a loggedIn method in `AuthService` so I can get a boolean about the user status? I want it for the `CanActivate` method and the `AuthService` looks like this:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
      return this.http.post<AuthResponseData>(
        'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=',
      {
         email,
         password,
         returnSecureToken: true
      }
      )
        .pipe(tap(resData => {
          this.handleAuthentication(
            resData.email,
            resData.localId,
            resData.idToken,
            +resData.expiresIn);
          })
        );
        }

  // tslint:disable-next-line:typedef
    private handleAuthentication(
      email: string,
      userId: string,
      token: string,
      expiresIn: number) {
        const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + expiresIn * 1000);
        const user = new User(
          email,
          userId,
          token,
          expirationDate
           );
        this.user.next(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once your login is successful then you can set the variable in the auth service to true and when logged out to false
And then create a method in the service as getauthstatus which you can access once you inject authservice class in canActivate constructor
Or more precise will be dont create the extra variable just check availability of the user object you are creating in getloggedin status and same way it can be injected in canActivate constructor

Comment: and the logout :
`
 logout(){
          this.isAuthenticatd = false;
          this.user.next();
          this.router.navigate(['/auth0']);
        }
The loggedIn method:
isLoggedIn(){
      if (this.isAuthenticatd === true )
     { return true;}
     else {return false}
   }   
}`

Comment: Some time it is like the angular tries to route when login is still not done, you need to make sure you call navigate once user is set properly in the service and then you try to check in guard that value is received when you call service via that

Comment: Your canactivate code also and are the http calls subscribed in the component?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dalhzf?file=tsconfig.json